# Half Radial Gradient CSS

Tags: css

Does anyone has a solution for this css gradient?
[Gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nExju.png)

This is the css I use now:

```
background: transparent radial-gradient(closest-side at 50% 50%, #202020 0%, #202020BC 18%, #82DB563C 100%, #83DC563B 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
```

border: 1px solid #83DC56;
opacity: 1;

Comment: you don't mention your problem here , please check this site to learn how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use an `ellipse at top` to get this kind of effect.  Here's an example I made for you. You of course can play around with the colors to get it to what you want.

```css
div {
background: transparent radial-gradient(ellipse at top, #202020 40%, #006400 100%, #39FF14 100%);
border: 1px solid #83DC56; opacity: 1;
height: 100px;
width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: you can omit the word `ellipse` since it's the default value